# Swift: Type of Expression is ambiguous without more context?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

After I query the Parse database I get an error with the following code:

```
if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successfully retrieved \(objects!.count) zip codes.", terminator: "")
            // Do something with the found objects
            if let zipCodes = objects! as? [PFObject] {
                if zipCodes.contains({ $0["Zipcode"] as? Int32 == usersZipCode}) { **<-----THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS**
                    print("your in!") // transition to the new screen
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("beginSignUp", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    self.messageLabelNotAvail.text = "Unfortunately, Patch is not available in your area or you have not typed in a correct US Zip Code."
                }
            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)", terminator: "")
        }
    }
}
```

If i replace Int32 to String, it works fine.. But my Zipcode in my parse database is a Number not a String. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the type of `usersZipCode`?

Comment: let usersZipCode = zipCode.text , it should be a Number type

Comment: Should it? I don't know what your `zipCode` variable is, but usually `text` properties are of type `String`

Comment: zipCode variable is an Int

Comment: Then `let usersZipCode = zipCode.text` makes no sense. `Int`s don't have `text` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if zipCodes.contains({ $0["Zipcode"] as? Int32 == usersZipCode}) { 
   //Rest of Code
}
```

Try:

```
if let target = Int32(usersZipCode) 
   where zipCodes.contains({ $0["Zipcode"] as? Int32 == target}) { 
     //Rest of Code
}
```

> **Clarification:** You can't compare things of different types in Swift. The reason it works when you cast to `String` but breaks when you cast to `Int32` seems to be that `usersZipCode` is of `String` type.